# using multiple update panels in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, coding-style

Hi I have this doubt,
I use four different update panels, that use the same timer as trigger. Now my questions are these.

1) Will the 4 update panels create 4 different HTTP requests to the server?
2) I'm using 4 different panels as the controls are located in different parts of the page, is there a way of putting them in the same update panel?
3) Is this a good coding practice?

Answer (score 0):

For simplicitly, you could have one timer update one of the update panels, and set the updatemode of the other three to always.  When the first one updates, the other three will update when the first one does.

That is an interesting scenario; I'm not 100% sure if four requests happen, but theoretically possible.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks, I like this idea. Yes right now all the panels have the same timer as trigger. I will try that out.

Answer (score 0):

1) I believe it shouldn't - only one event was raised/posted to the server.  You can also always use a tool like fiddler to verify these things

2) If there is HTML between the update panels, no, unless you don't mind including the static portions of your page between the updated areas in the update panel as well; however, at that point you're not really benefiting much by using the panels (you might as well do a full page refresh at that point).